# Matrix multiplication using multithreading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement matrix multiplication using multithreading in C.
I am calculating the sum of each position in the new matrix and returning it to the `main` function using the `pthread_exit`. Why are the threads not returning correct value of `sum` to the `main` function? I don't understand how to return values using `pthread_exit` and retrieve them using `pthread_join`.
I am bad with pointers, so please help!

```
void * func(void * arg)
{
    z++;
    printf("\n %d thread created", z);

    int row = (int)arg / m;
    int col = (int)arg % y;

    sleep(10);

    int sum = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        sum += (ar1[row][k] * ar2[k][col]);

    printf("\n The thread has calculated sum = %d", sum);
    printf("\n Thread is complete");

    void * retval = (void *)sum;
    pthread_exit(retval);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[100];

    printf("\n Enter the row and column size of first matrix: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    printf("\n Enter the elements of the first matrix: ");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &ar1[i][j]);

    printf("\n Enter the row and column size of second matrix: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    printf("\n Enter the elements of the second matrix: ");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
            scanf("%d", &ar2[i][j]);

    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");

    printf("\n The First Matrix is \n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", ar1[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");

    printf("\n The Second Matrix is \n");
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf("%d ", ar2[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");

    if (n != x)
    {
        printf("\n Multiplication is not possible");
        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (m * y); i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, func, (void *)i);
        sleep(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (m * y); i++)
    {
        void ** retval;
        pthread_join(tid[i], retval);

        int sum = (int)retval;
        printf("%d", sum);
    }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");

    printf("\n The Third Matrix is \n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf("%d ", ar3[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------------------------");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `main`, change the definition of `retval` to `void *retval;`, and pass `&retval` to `pthread_join`.

Comment: `(void * ) i` --> Converting an  `int` to `void*` is undefined behavior unless that `int` was first derived from a valid pointer.

Comment: @chux nope, dereferencing the resulting pointer is undefined behaviour, but casting itself is not.

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough: "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation." §6.3.2.3 5.  As I see it though, round-tripping `int` --> .`void*` --> `int` may fail to provide the same `int` value.